# BASH: Show last modified files with date modified

Tags: bash

I'm trying to list any files which were modified within the last 60 mins. I use `find` but it only shows the path and not the date when it was last modified. How do I do this?

```
# Missing last modified date
find . -mmin -60 -not -path './.git/*'
```

Answer (score 4):

With GNU find

```
find . -mmin -60 ! -path './.git/*' -printf '%t\t%p\n'

Mon Jul 25 08:19:42.0000000000 2016     ./file.txt
```

> **%t**     File's last modification time in the format returned by the C `ctime' function.
>
> **%p**     File's name.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using GNU `find`, add the `-ls` action:

```
find . -mmin -60 -not -path './.git/*' -ls
```

Otherwise, POSIX-ly:

```
find . -mmin -60 -not -path './.git/*' -exec ls -l {} +
```

You can also use `stat` instead of `ls` to get only the desired info:

```
find . -mmin -60 -not -path './.git/*' -exec stat -c '%y : %n' +
```